# How does ASP.NET compare to PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net

It seems to me that everyone on the Internet is talking about PHP/ROR/Python, but *few* care to mention ASP.NET. Ironically, here in China, *most* books concerning web development on the shelf in the bookstores are about ASP.NET. I just want to know what is "wrong" with ASP.NET on these web forums. I am really new to web development, and I've just learned a little PHP, and haven't touched anything ASP.NET yet. I would like to know the pros and cons of PHP and ASP.NET. Thank you very much!

Comment: ASP is obsolete (and I believe unsupported). Do you mean ASP.NET?

Comment: @John Saunders: yes, actually I mean ASP/ASP.NET :)

Comment: @TheBigO: Sorry, I'll do that right away! Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: @xcz: then just say "ASP.NET", not "ASP/ASP.NET". There are still people who have to program in classic ASP, so saying "ASP" will be confusing.

Comment: @xcz: there is no such thing as "ASP.NET/ASP". Why did you edit your question to include that non-existent term?

Comment: @xcz: to direct a comment to someone, you need to use at least the first three letters of their name. In any case, there is also no such word as "learnt".

Comment: @John - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/learnt

Comment: @John: Thank you again, really appreciate your help. There are still many things on this platform for me to learn. But, why do you say that the past participle form "learnt" of the word "learn" does not exist? As far as I know, both "learnt" and "learned" would work here. Perhaps my English teacher has teached(NOT taught?) me the wrong thing? :)

Comment: @Phill: the OP should see [When do you use 'learnt' and when learned](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/when-do-you-use-learnt-and-when-learned) and then decide how unusual he wants to be.

Comment: @xcz: your English teacher has taught you a rare usage, all but obsolete in normal speech.

Comment: @xcz: judging from your questions on SO, I'd suggest you be certain to learn object-oriented PHP if you must use PHP at all. You will otherwise be at a disadvantage - stuck using a procedural scripting language while others are using object-oriented programming languages.

Comment: @xcz: in fact, I'd say that PHP is nearly as functional as Classic ASP and has many of the same disadvantages. That's why ASP was replaced by ASP.NET ten years ago.

Comment: @John - I'm from New Zealand, living in Australian, it doesn't look unusual to me. Both words are used. I learnt both at school. (will note, it's only ever Americans that complain about particular use of words. Example, Labor vs Labour, Color vs Colour.)

Comment: @Phill: some would say, "Ahah! That explains it!", but I'm a fan of Peter Jackson and Lucy Lawless, so wouldn't be among them. In any case, I never see "learnt" except in old poetry. My spell checker even calls it out as an error.

Comment: @John: that really helps me a lot, dear sir, about "learned vs learnt" :)

Comment: @Phill: BTW, "Labour" doesn't look old-fashioned to me, whereas "learnt" looks like a spelling error.

Comment: @John, growing up using the word makes it hard to change habit. I only called you out because technically it is a word, it's just rare to use the word in American English and British English now-a-days. (I'm not sure why it's more common in Australia/New Zealand however) - We digress tho. :)

Comment: @Phill: in any case, any learned discussion about the word "learnt" should take place over in [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/when-do-you-use-learnt-and-when-learned).

Comment: @John: about OOP PHP and procedural PHP, I have some general knowledge of these two programming approaches, and I was told that PHP has evolved to become an OOP language. My take is that using a framework would involve mostly with the OOP, while writing code from scratch would be procedural, am I corret?

Comment: @xcz: I haven't done enough PHP programming to know. You've probably done more than I have. I wrote a simple SOAP service to help someone. It seemed that the SOAP support would work just as well for procedural as for OOP. The trick then would be to ignore the procedural support.  To put it more strongly than politely, "bad enough it's a scripting language, at least use it in an object-oriented manner".

Comment: @John: Thank you. I heard a lot about the cons about PHP compared to Python, ROR etc.,but it seems to me that here in China there are more companies needing PHP programmers. So I am facing a hard situation here :(

Comment: @xcz: I wasn't so much saying that PHP is bad - but that you should use it in an object-oriented manner. Otherwise, you will not understand OO.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with ASP.NET. Except the fact it's a Microsoft technology, so some communities avoid to mention it, or mention it only to say it's evil, without giving a real explanation.

Everything depends on the communities. Here, on StackOverflow, I see more questions about ASP.NET than about PHP. There are other websites which are more ASP.NET oriented.

If you want to choose what to use, **try both**. **This is the only way for you to make a real choice**, without being influenced by an opinion of a person who thinks that PHP sucks and is used only by beginners who don't know anything about programming, or a person who thinks that everything related to Microsoft is bad.

Comment: Agreed!  If you don't know which one you prefer, you're likely not working on a project big enough to require consideration for performance & scalability.  [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web) is a free ASP.NET IDE, and [Eclipse with PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt) is a great free IDE for playing with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are referring to the ASP.NET, since ASP is obsolete and deprecated in some sense.

It's really difficult to compare PHP/Python/Ruby to ASP.NET. It would make more sense to compare frameworks. PHP has some popular frameworks called Zend and CakePHP. Python has Django. Ruby got, of course, Ruby on Rails. ASP.NET has MVC.

There is **nothing wrong** with ASP.NET. In fact, ASP.NET MVC2 is very neat. If you use it with Visual Studio, you basically don't need anything else, since you can debug your application with the visual studio webserver that comes with the IDE. MSDN has a lot of documentation on the MVC framework and a lot of people on stackoverflow are experts.

One downside is that you will need to host your site on Microsoft Server, which is typically more costly than Linux. If you are used to Linux, you will also need to consider some ramp up time and learning cost, because Windows Server is quite different. You might also want to use SQL Server 2008 because Microsoft technologies usually go well together.

There are a lot of things you need to consider when you want to create website with something you are not familiar with. **I recommend you to just get started somewhere. If you are learning  in order to acquire skills that may help you get some job offers, learn the skills you need.** If ASP.NET is something used a lot in China, I would recommend you to pick up ASP.NET MVC and start developing, although this will cost you some money up front. Otherwise, go with PHP/Python/Ruby because there are tons of sites that use these languages and frameworks based on these languages.

For ASP.NET MVC2, [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman) is a good starting point.

By the way, stackoverflow is built on [ASP.NET MVC + SQL Server 2008 + C#](http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

You got an IDE full of features and access to whole .NET infrastructure if using asp.net comparing to php.

Comment: You also have an IDE full of features if you write code in PHP. Although many programmers choose to avoid an IDE in favor of editors like vim/emacs either way.

Comment: @TheBigO - Many of those programmers however write procedural PHP.

Comment: @TheBigO: which PHP IDE has features? Also, he's still right about access to .NET.

Comment: @John Saunders: Every IDE has features -- that's what makes them IDEs. IDEs that support PHP include Netbeans, Eclipse, Zend, PHP Komodo, PHP Designer, PHPEd, etc. I didn't say he was wrong or right about access to .NET.

Comment: @The: I guess the question would be, "define 'feature'". I'm not saying that, say, Eclipse doesn't have good PHP support - I've only written a handful of PHP programs, and used Notepad to do it. I've used Eclipse before with Java, but don't know whether it's any better than Notepad in understanding PHP. I guess that's what I'm asking you to define.

Comment: @John: IDEs that support PHP well have the typical features that you'd expect, like code completion and syntax highlighting. That's already much better than what Notepad would do. They also have refactoring support and automatic brace indentation, etc.

Comment: @The: thanks. That does a great job of contradicting the "IDE" portion of this answer (which is what I wanted you to do ).

Comment: In conclusion, this post does not answer the question. It just creates more questions and subjective arguments.

Comment: I've used PHP and ColdFusion and feel that ASP.NET with C# is a much more robust solution. When comparing other IDE's Visual Studio 2010 is very pleasing to use.